# Image is not shown from mongodb in ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert-image

I am trying to insert an image in mongodb, then I want to fetch and show the image in ejs template.

My code:

**index.js**

```
var uploadDir=__dirname+'/uploads';
 var images=Date.now()+'.jpg';
var storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(request, file, callback){
        callback(null, uploadDir);
        },
        filename:function(request, file, callback){
            console.log(file);
            callback(null, images);
            }
    });
    var upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('photo');

/*============== blog Insert============*/
router.post('/add', upload, function(req, res, next){
    new blogs({
        title: req.body.title,
        description:req.body.description,
        categories:req.body.category,
        img:images,
        date:Date.now()
        }).save(function(err, doc){
             res.send('Inserted');
        });
    });
```

the Image is successfully inserted into collection as name of file and also storing in disk space. 
When I try to fetch the image by writing:

```
<img src="./routes/uploads/<%= blogdata.img%>" />
```

in my view page the image is absent. I turn to the viewsouce code of that page and its showing the full path i.e

```
<img src="./routes/uploads/1459772396796.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Show the code where you define the routes/static file serving for uploads.  The relative path doesn't have meaning as a url and normally your URL wouldn't include the `routes` either so the page source should say `/uploads/1459772396796.jpg`.

Per your comment you have two static dirs, not sure you can do that, but regardless the path as I said does not include the `routes` part.

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes/uploads')));

Comment: Thanks. That should go in your question because it is a critical part to answer.